# Detect if Wake on LAN host is available

Tags: windows, networking, wake-on-lan

Is there a possibility to detect, if a Wake on LAN target is available and listening on the network?

---

I have several Windows 10 machines with Intel I211 Ethernet Adapter running. For all, Wake on LAN is enabled and working well most of the times.

But sometimes it does not (e.g. Windows Update disables WoL, someone cut the main power, etc.).

Currently, I send a WoL magic package and start to ping the machine until it succeeds. But I don't know, if the machine is booting, which may take a while, or if the machine didn't wake up at all. Therefore, it would be great to have a direct indication in my controller application, if the machine available and is listening for magic packages.

My first idea was that the Intel adapter could be able to respond to pings, but this doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [Wake-on-LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)`magic packet` is broadcast via UDP (a connectionles protocol) there is AFAIK no way until the pc is up and the network stack fully working to answer to a (IP based) ping.

Remember the WOL sends the MAC-address not an IP and the time until the pc is up (if at all) depends on the [power state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Power_states) (s0..s5).

Comment: My hope was that it may be possible to configure the ethernet adapter to answer a ping or some other request, even though the main OS is shut off.